# Error when the application did become active

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm getting this on the xcode logs:

> [_UIRemoteKeyboards proxy]_block_invoke Failed to access remote service: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.UIKit.KeyboardManagement.hosted was invalidated from this process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.UIKit.KeyboardManagement.hosted was invalidated from this process.}

Any idea as to what could have caused this?

Answer (score 1):

This error may be because your Keyboard needs full Access.

Open the **info.plist** from your Keyboard Target.

Set Value **Yes** for key

> RequestsOpenAccess

You can also make sure that your keyboard extension has full access, by the following method

```
func hasOpenAccess() -> Bool {
    UIPasteboard.general.string = "TEST"
    return UIPasteboard.general.hasStrings
}
```

Comment: Could this be due to emulator-specific, in any way?

Comment: Is it still crashing after adding these request Open access key? you can go to keyboard Settings->General->Keyboards->Keyboards and select your keyboard.. then and enable "Allow full access" there..

Comment: I'm not using any custom keyboard. So, I can't find that key-value pair at all.
It came up randomly when I brought my app from background after a long time. I wasn't using keyboard before I pushed it to the backgound...

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error earlier today. Turned out I was trying to manipulate the keyboard while stuck in an infinite loop. I would recommend stepping through your code and verifying that you are not stuck in one yourself.

The strange thing is that infinite loops typically stop program execution / make themselves obvious in the stack trace. Mine didn't do that, however; it only printed the error you mentioned in your question.

Once I fixed the code that produced the loop, the error went away.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have seen this error, but before I had error in console from Firestore which was not getting enough permission to download User.

To fix that I changed rules for Firestore to the following:

```
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
  allow read: if request.auth == null;
```

Maybe this will help.