# App crash in Xcode 11.0 beta with Code 4097

Tags: swift5, xcode11

Getting below error with my iOS project which is working fine below Xcode 11.0 but In Xcode 11.0 beta, I am getting below error.

> [_UIRemoteKeyboards proxy]_block_invoke Failed to access remote
>   service: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to
>   service on pid 0 named com.apple.UIKit.KeyboardManagement.hosted"
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service on pid 0 named
>   com.apple.UIKit.KeyboardManagement.hosted}

can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Maybe related, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57161223/error-when-the-application-did-become-active

Comment: tried that but not working

Comment: did you find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated xcode to 11.0 and it's working for me now